# База данных на c++ без String

Tags: c++

Вообщем, нужно написать базу данных на c++. Она должна с помощью одного из пунктов меню принимать ввод Ф.И.О, трех предметов и оценок по ним. Строки использовать, нельзя. Соответственно нужны динамические чаровые массивы.Я написал примерно, что-то вроде этого, но при вводе оно ждет ввод всех 255 символов. И даже если полностью забить массив то на выводе получаться крякозябры. А также строки между собой не разделяются насколько я понял. А также получается что при вводе должен учитываться пробелы например "Алексей Петрович Слухов".

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL,"rus");
int rows;
cout<<"Количество человек - ";
cin>>rows;
int bkv=255;
char **fio=new char*[rows];
for (int i=0;i<rows;i++)
{
    fio[i]=new char[bkv];
}
for (int i=0;i<rows;i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<bkv;j++)
    {
        cin>>fio[i][j];
    }
}
for (int i=0;i<rows;i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<bkv;j++)
    {
        cout<<fio[i][j];
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
for (int i=0;i<rows;i++)
{
    delete [] fio[i];
}
delete [] fio;
system("pause>0");
}
```

Comment: Для чтения строк -- [man fgets](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)

Answer (score 0):

я понимаю, что некоторые преподаватели перегибают палку и рвут струны (string - струна), но все же возможно. Собственно ввод и вывод можно написать вот так

```
for (int i=0;i<rows;i++)
{
        cin>>fio[i];
}
for (int i=0;i<rows;i++)
{
    cout<<fio[i];
    cout<<endl;
}
```

и все будет работать. И не нужно вложенных циклов.

если нужно читать строки с пробелами, то это где то так. Вместо

```
cin>>fio[i];
```

пишем такое

```
cin.getline(fio[i], bkv);
```

С этим есть одна маленькая проблема - после ввода числа количества, в входном потоке остается перевод строки и он читается сразу. Поэтому нужно его проигнорировать. И весь цикл чтения будет такой

```
cin.ignore(100, '\n'); // тут на самом деле и 2 хватило, но можно и что то лучше придумать
for (int i=0;i<rows;i++)
{
        cin.getline(fio[i], bkv);
}
```

P.S. в коде есть много других ужасов, но оставим их на совести преподавателя.

Comment: может, проблема у меня, но cin >> fio[i] считывает до первого пробела, поэтому кладёт в массив только фамилию, а имя уже положит в следующий массив (тк оно в потоке застряло)

Answer (score 0):

вариант KoVadim у меня не работает (cin считывает всё до первого пробела), так что предложу свой вариант:

```
    for (int i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        cin>>fio[i];
        for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; fio[i][j] != '\0'; j++)
                count++;
            fio[i][count] = ' ';
            cin >> (fio[i] + count + 1);
        }
    }
```